# How to prevent PHP on a virtualhost/website from writing to another virtualhost's/website's directory on the same Apache server?

Tags: linux, php, security, apache-2.4, permissions

I want to prevent virtualhost #1 from writing or reading to virtualhost #2 without losing writing access to the www-data at all (because the applications need to write to the directory).

My current site configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ...
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public/
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.org
  ...
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/public/
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Both have the following kind of permissions:

```
drwxrws--- webmaster-com www-data example.com
drwxrws--- webmaster-org www-data example.org
```

My problem is that PHP code/scripts executed on `example.org` can read configurations of the `example.com` website, with often MySQL passwords in it.

Comment: Which user/group do you use for your PHP scripts? how does Apache interact with your PHP application?

Comment: Running <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?> gives www-data. I have no idea how Apache is interacting with PHP. I have not changed anything of Apache besides the `sites-available` configurations. @Tom

Comment: Are you using mod_php, FastCGI, or PHP-FPM?

Comment: I installed PHP with apt-get install php7.0 on Debian 9.6. I guess it is mod_php since I can find php7.0 in the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ folder. @Tom

Comment: I think you wont be able to limit read access then. If you use FastCGI, you could use a different instance for each customer, each with their own user/group permissions.

Comment: Take a look at PHP configuration directive [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). You can set it in your apache configuration for each virtual using `php_admin_value "open_basedir" "/var/www/example.com/"` or `php_admin_value "open_basedir" "/var/www/example.org/"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP configuration directive [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir).

> `open_basedir string`
>
> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is NOT affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.

To configure it per virtualhost, use [`php_admin_value`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) configuration directive like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ...
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public/
  php_admin_value "open_basedir" "/var/www/example.com/"
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.org
  ...
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/public/
  php_admin_value "open_basedir" "/var/www/example.org/"
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Be sure to use `php_admin_value` and not plain `php_value` because:

> `php_admin_value name value`
>
> Sets the value of the specified directive. This can not be used in .htaccess files. Any directive type set with php_admin_value can not be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set().

Comment: This works for me! Thanks a lot. Do you think it might be a better/more efficient choice to go and look at what FastCGI offers?

Comment: It depends, I'm hosting several PHP web sites for different customers and tihs configuration was always sufficient for me. In combination with extended ACL I have effectively isolated their folders so nobody can read/write what he is not supposed to. FastCGI also allows such isolation, but I am too lazy to try this as my solution works fine.